# When should we use the factory method pattern? (instead of composition)

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism, factory-method

As per `GOF` book, `Factory method pattern`

> > Define an interface for creating an object, but let the subclasses decide which class to instantiate. Factory method lets a class defer instantiation to subclass.

*Structure of the pattern*

```
public abstract class Factory {
    public abstract IProduct createProduct();
    private void performCriticalJob(){
        IProduct product = createProduct();
        product.serve();
    }
    public void executeJob(){
        //some code
        performCriticalJob();
        //some more code
    }
}


public interface IProduct {
    public void serve();
}
```

1. Factory needs an object (whose concrete class is not known or whose concrete class may change as per the different application type ) to perform a task.
2. As it does not know  which class to instantiate, one standard contract is set for the type of object needed, this contract is put in an Interface.
3. Base factory class declares an `abstract` method to return an object of type as above defined `interface`.
   It lets subclasses decide and provide the implementation of object creation.
4. For completion of the task it needs an object which it simply fetches by calling the `abstract` method.

**Question**  *Favour Composition over inheritance.*
Factory method above uses inheritance to get the concrete products. Also subclasses need to be implement the createProduct which will create and return the ConcreteProduct. Instead of Subclassing the Factory class, if abstract method is removed from it (which makes the Factory class as non abstract class). Now Factory class can be composed by the new classes and concrete product objects can be injected in it as below example.

To achieve the intent in the scenarios as defined by Factory method  pattern why just normal polymorphism is not being used as below ? I know factory method pattern has something more which I am missing but going by the favouting composition over inheritance, i find the below way ,to solve the same problem in same scenario , a better way over the way as in `Factory method`. What is the advantage of `Factory method` over the method below ?

```
public abstract class PolymorphismWay {
    private void performCriticalJob(IProduct product){
        product.serve();
        //some code
    }
    public void executeJob(IProduct product){
        //some code
        performCriticalJob(product);
        //some more code
    }
}
```

Now instead of asking users to create child factory classes and returning the concrete object of product by implementing the createProduct method, users can directly provide the object of concrete classes implementing IProduct to `executeJob`.

[**EDIT**] Thanks for the answers and comments but same thought as expressed in comments and answers I also had which also brought some confusion. I studied the **`GOF`** factory method pattern. It has used an example of a *Framework for applications creating documents of various types*. My questions are doubts those arouse after this study.

The sites and blogs are based nothing but the reflection of the understanding which the authour has for the pattern, he / she may or maynot have read, understood the actual intent of the pattern. Understanding the classes is not the main objective. Design pattern should be studied considering what scenario and what problem comes for which the best solution following the good OOP principles ( or violating them the least and voilating them along with having a very good reason to do so). That best solution is the solution as explained by any `design pattern`. `GOF` is a standard book which explains it quite well. But still there are few gaps or doubts which is the main reason for this question.

Comment: In your second example, how would an IProduct get instantiated?

Comment: I don't see polymorphism in your code snippet :/

Comment: By polymorphism I mean the method accepting the parameter of Interface IProduct type. Instead of asking users to create child factory classes and returing the concrete object of product, users can directly provide the object of concrete classes implementing `IProduct` to `executeJob`.

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer I have edited the question. `IProduct` is an interface.

Comment: The whole point of a factory is to create objects. IMHO, the methods performCriticalJob() and executeJob() do not belong in a factory class.

Comment: In the changes that you're proposing, Factory is no longer a factory; so how would you create the IProduct instances?

Comment: @Maurice Perry, see the intent of factory method. Its a creational pattern. The intent is to **Define an interface for creating an object, but let the subclasses decide which class to instantiate. Factory method lets a class defer instantiation to subclass.**

Comment: I agree with @MauricePerry, I think that your second example is not a factory method pattern at all.

Comment: its the subclasses (like in frameworks) defined later by the application developers using the code written to provide the concrete product. design patterns provide a way to solve a problem in a scenario, but with good oop principle of favouring composition over inheritance, same in same scenario same problem can be solved using the second way. I have included in question that the users will aggregate the Base class and then inject the concrete product rather than going for extending the base class.

Comment: I am saying why factory method type solution was proposed, why not the second way was proposed as it solves the same purpose folling oop good principles

Comment: @nits.kk no it doesn't: it doesn't create instances.

Comment: OK, in the initial code, performCriticalJob() can create a product whenever it needs to; it can create zero or as many instances as needed. In your modified version, the caller has to create one (and only one) product and pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Also, you can create the factory once, and never have to worry about products any more.

Comment: There are few comments about 2nd example. Yes I do agree it is not factory pattern. It is the alternate polymorphic way, I kept the class name initially the same to compare but as it causes confusion so I changed the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know factory method pattern has something more which I am missing but going by the favouting composition over inheritance, i find the below way ,to solve the same problem in same scenario

There are several advantages that you get when using the *Factory Method* pattern instead of plain old composition as shown in your question :

**1. Separation of concerns and open-closed principle**  : You create one factory subclass for each related group of objects. This factory subclass is responsible for creating only those products that belong to a particular group. `ABCProductFactory` will only be concerned with creating `ABCProduct1`, `ABCProduct2`, etc. `CDEProductFactory` will only be concerned with creating `CDEProduct1`, `CDEProduct2` and so on. For every new product group, you create a new subclass rather than modifying an existing class. If you went with the composition approach, some other class would be responsible for creating the product and passing it into your `Factory`. As your product variety increases to say `ZZZProduct1` and `ZZZProduct2` and so on, this class would soon explode to a huge size with too many if-else conditions to  check which product subclass to create. You would eventually realize this and define one class for creating each related group of products.

**2. Product creation and product processing has a contract :** The factory method pattern is very similar to the *template-method* pattern in this case as it specifies a template for the operations that need to be performed on an object after it has been created. This allows you to ensure that once a product is created, it will always go through the same steps as any other product created by the factory. Compare this to the *Composition* example in your question where there is no fixed contract for what steps an `IProduct` should go through once it has been created. I could create a class called `Factory2` with a single `public` method called `performCriticalJob`. Nothing forces me to have an `executeJob` method in `Factory2`. Even if I add an `executeJob` method to `Factory2`, nothing forces me to call `performCriticalJob` inside `executeJob`. You could fix this issue by using the *template* pattern.

It should be clear by now that the *Factory Method* pattern basically binds the object creation and object processing together in one class. With your composition example, you would have a lot of moving pieces and no one governing how they should work together.

**Bottom line :** In your case, use the *Factory Method* pattern when you want object creation and object processing to have a fixed contract such that all objects go through the same processing once created. Use your composition example where there is no contract needed for the steps to be followed after the object has been created.

Comment: +1 for the second point. Somewhat the answer I guess I was looking for. But the point 1 is still little doubtful as Instead of having if else statements there could be as many number of classes as are the products and each can create the product and inject in the factory class. But yes there is no enforcement of a contract here...I will wish to have some more good thoughts as ptovided by you and in case there are not other such thoughts then I will mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: @nits.kk One class for creating each object. 100 factories for 100 products? You are better off just using `new` instead! You see, a factory is supposed to encapsulate the creation of related products. There is no value in having one factory class corresponding to each product. (I deliberately chose to ignore the term *doubtful* but it really does have a negative connotation to it)

Comment: yes agreed if the products are of same super type (follow same contract) and are related (related to same factory) then following the factory method pattern the `createProduct` will have to decide which  product to create (easy way may b switch case based on the parameter). The composition way also can do the same and inject the decided product based on a parameter.

Comment: @nits.kk I already explained in point 1 that you could achieve the objectives using composition as well but you will realize that your class gets bigger over time and decide to split it into multiple classes. The factory method pattern enforces OCP and SRP by design as explained in point 1. Also, a factory is supposed to create objects that have the same super type. Even then, these subclasses can further be grouped into related subclasses. It seems to me that you are trying to say that your approach is better. It's not. It has a lot of moving parts. I explained 2 advantages. Choice is yours.

Comment: I know factory method is the best way to solve *a problem* in *a scenario*, I know I have missed some thing in understanding the problem or scenario or the pattern intent , i just found composition solving the same thing. Subclasses need to provide the concrete products and are bound to follow a contract and once object is created the necessary action if any can be executed by using Factory method pattern. This point you have already told in answer which actually is impressive. :)

Comment: @ChetanKinger about this sentence "operations that need to be performed on an object after it has been created", why not just call the method in said object constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, you are insisting that your `Factory` class has only ONE kind of clients who always use the class by either extending it (the code #1) or passing a newly-created IProduct to its methods (the code #2). The whole purpose of this kind of clients is to make the `Factory` the ability of receiving a newly-created IProduct.

How about normal clients who don't care about all of the things above! These even don't care whether the class is Factory or not. Thus, they don't want a method requiring an IProduct as in your code #2.

Indeed, you should rename your `Factory` class to something else (e.g., `XXX`), the class is not "factory"! But some of its methods are "factory". You see, the pattern name is "Factory Method", not "Factory" or "Factory Object". In contrast, in Abstract Factory pattern, an abstract factory is really a factory object.

P/S: a proper composition approach is passing an abstract factory into the constructor of XXX.

Answer (score 1):

Since we know the Factory Method Pattern relies on inheritance, this problem is much easier to reason about if we begin without the Factory Method piece and simply ask, *when should we favor inheritance over composition*?

We already know the answer to that question is, "*not often*" because the GoF has told us to favor composition in general. Yet there are real-world scenarios where inheritance exists. The animal kingdom may be the quintessential example. When inheritance actually occurs within a domain, it makes sense to model it the same way in our code. And that's when we should consider the Factory Method Pattern as well. Consider it only when you've already decided that inheritance is appropriate to the context. First choose inheritance, then choose the creational pattern.  Don't introduce Factory Method and then be forced into an inheritance relationship that otherwise wouldn't apply.

A more opinionated answer is: never use the Factory Method Pattern in modern code. Stick with composition relationships, all wired together within a dependency-injection container. The GoF patterns are not advice. They are a collection of designs from the 1980s. Similar to the way Singleton is now considered to be more anti-pattern than pattern due to its negative side effects, Factory Method has very little applicability in modern code. In those rare cases where it may be appropriate, you'll know it because you'll already be using inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Read again the definition you've provided:

> Define an interface for **creating** an object, but let the subclasses decide which class to instantiate. Factory method lets a class defer instantiation to subclass.

Which a bit contradicts your first statement:

> Factory needs an object (whose concrete class is not known or whose concrete class may change as per the different application type ) **to perform a task**

The factory purpose is *creating* objects, not *performing tasks*.

In fact, event if it will perform a task it's only to be able to create the object for you.
After you get the object from the factory, you can perform your critical job.

And about *Favour Composition over inheritance*, the factory method can *compose* the object for you as well and deliver back an object composition.

There are many good examples of factory pattern - for example in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and [blackwasp](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/FactoryMethod_2.aspx)

**Edit - Concerning the GoF `Application` example**

The GoF example of the `Application` uses a `Template Method` for the `Factory Method`.
the `Application` defines the factory method and some operations around it, but the sub-classes of the `Application` decide which `Document` to create.

You have suggested, not to use factory method. Instead, to create the `Document` somewhere else and "injected" to the `Application` (a.k.a dependency injection).
You have not described where will the `Document` be created (it could still be a factory).
Now the `Application` sub-classes doesn't have any control on the creation of the `Document`. This changes the behavior and design of the system completely.

It doesn't mean that its bad or good, it's just a different approach.
In real-life scenarios you have to carefully examine the problem at hand and decide which design would fit the most.

Comment: @ Ofir Winegarten these exact thoughts I had as but please studty the Framework example of Application creating Documents from the `GOF` which explains the pattern, it will bring some insights :)

Comment: As per factory method standard structure It is the users of the code who will subclass the factory and provide implementation for createProduct where concrete product is created. So in the second way of solvg this case :  similarly users can instead of subclassing the base class can have  a instance of it and can then inject the concrete product after creating the concrete product.

Comment: Yes, but there can be many subclasses with different implementations of `createProduct`. This is the whole point.

Comment: Similarly there can be many classes composing the class, instead of extending it.